# Copy specific row to another workbook based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy row(A:E), row(F:AH), and row(AL)from the active workbook to row(A:E), row(G:AI), row(AJ) of another workbook. Here's the code that I'm working on. I saw it here and just edited it.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim ret

ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls, .xlsx*),*.xls, .xlsx*", _
                                  Title:="Select data file for Monitoring Log")
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Macro Template")

strSearch = "Newly Distributed"

With ws1

    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Range("AL" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("AL7:AL" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
        Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With

    '~~> Remove any filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

'~~> Destination File
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(ret)
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Source")

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row + 1
    Else
        lRow = 1
    End If

    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With

wb2.Save
wb2.Close
```

This code copies the entire row. How can I revise it to copy specific rows.

Comment: The question is not clear. You seem to be using "row" meaning "column" at some points. Please post sample input data and expected output.

Comment: My mistake, data from the column a:e will be copied to column a:e of another workbook. Instead of using entire row, I want to copy selected data from the columns of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
```

with

```
copyFrom.Columns("A:E").Copy .Cells(lRow, "A")
copyFrom.Columns("F:AH").Copy .Cells(lRow, "G")
copyFrom.Columns("AL").Copy .Cells(lRow, "AJ")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the source code, i just could see you copy the data from the column AL to another worksheet. 
I modified your code and it successfully copy to the another worksheet. The copy function could be written in 1 line instead of multiple line.

```
Option Explicit
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim strSearch As String

Sub Test()

Dim ret

ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xls, .xlsx*),*.xls, .xlsx*", _
                                  Title:="Select data file for Monitoring Log")
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Macro Template")

strSearch = "Newly Distributed"

With ws1

    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "AL").End(xlUp).Row
    'lRow = .Range("AL" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("AL7:AL" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
    End With

End With

'~~> Destination File
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(ret)
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Source")

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lRow2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Else
        lRow2 = 1
    End If

    'copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    ws1.Range("AL8:AL" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & lRow2)
End With

    '~~> Remove any filters
    ws1.AutoFilterMode = False

wb2.Save
wb2.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I want to happen is to copy data of column(A:E) to column(A:E) of another workbook as well as column(F:AH) to column (G:AI).

Comment: you could modify the code `ws1.Range("AL8:AL" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & lRow2)` to fulfill your need. just change the range. As your question not clearly mentioned that you got anything need to be filtered from that columns or not, so i just provide the solution based on your posted code for your reference. Hope it help

Comment: Thanks. By the way, how can I copy the row limited only to columns A to AJ instead of copying the entire row. I've tried using    copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows("1:36") but It doesn't work.

Comment: From A to J or AJ? The following code show you copy from A-E at workbook 1 to A-E at workbook2 `ws1.Range("A8:E" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & lRow2)` You could put +1 afther lRow2 to append your result. Just change E to AJ if you which to copy from A until AJ

Comment: I only need to copy A:AJ. Thanks for your response. :)